# Is there a difference between "ovunque" vs. "dovunque"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, difference

In a previous question I wrote *Credo che pressocché **dovunque** le persone parlino ...*, but it was changed to *Credo che pressocché **ovunque** le persone parlino ...*, replacing *dovunque* with *ovunque*.

Can anyone explain the reason why one should prefer *ovunque* over *dovunque* in that case?

After consulting some dictionaries, I'm still unsure about what the difference is.

Comment: But *pressocché* is wrong anyway.

Comment: I notice 'pressocché' (double 'c') is used in the answers below. Is this a variant spelling for 'pressoché'?

Answer (score 7):

They are interchangeable, as they have exactly the same meaning.

However, since one starts with a vowel and one with a consonant, the usage of one of the two can be preferable in the way they sound.

> Credo che pressocché ***dovunque*** le persone parlino ...

is completely fine and I wouldn't have bothered in correcting it. However I agree that

> Credo che pressocché ***ovunque*** le persone parlino ...

pleases my ear a little better, since losing the consonant makes the whole sentence flow more smoothly.

That being said, I think ***ovunque*** is less common in the spoken language than ***dovunque*** and it is also a little bit more highbrow.

Answer (score 7):

They are interchangeable, as *ovunque* means *dovunque*. They are like *tra* and *fra*: Although they are synonyms, you generally avoid some word combinations, such as *fra frati* and *tra travi*.

As for using *pressoché dovunque* or *pressoché ovunque*, Google NGrams shows the latter is used more often.

[image: screenshot]

Furthermore, looking for *presso**c**ché dovunque* versus *presso**c**ché ovunque*, I get the following. (There are two *c* after *presso*.)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Notare che i due grafici hanno scale molto diverse (contare gli zeri dopo la virgola).

Comment: Personally, I'd remove the graph with *_pressocché_. With the same logic, we'd find in Ngram also graphs for *_qual'è_, *_consegnamo_ or *_accellerare_.

Comment: @DaG That graph is pertinent, since *pressocché* is the variant spelling some people use for *pressoché* and *pressocché* is used in the [first revision of the question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/revisions/1360/1), which somebody wrongly edited.

Comment: I know that, but since it is a dubious spelling, the graph only proves that _someone_ uses it, which is marginally interesting, since it also would hold for every other dubious spelling, as in my examples.

Comment: @DaG It could be, but the OP expressly used *pressocché*, so it isn't that unrelated.